# Javascript SDK automatically login

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, sdk

I'am trying to get the Login button from Facebook to work on my website using the Javascript SDK. If the user is logged on, I get the email address back. This works. But on the page where I have my Facebook Login button, I also have the normal login for my website. (username & password). But when I go to my login page, the page automatically loads the Facebook button and the Facebook login dialog appears. But I don't want to load this button automatically. I want that users always have to press the login button for Facebook. Is this possible?

This is my code:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
        appId: 'MY_APP_ID', // App ID
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true,

});
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       alert('Good to see you, ' + response.email + '.');
     });
   } else {
     alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 });
});

// Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FB.getLoginStatus` method is used to know whether user has logged in or not

`FB.login` is used to prompt login page to authenticate and authorize the app.

you are calling FB.getLoginStatus method and not bothering about the response and firing fb.login button always.

If you always want user to click login button don't use `FB.getLoginStatus`

Use this code

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
            channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
          });
        };
        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function(d){
           var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
           if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
           ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
         }(document));
      </script>

      <div class="fb-login-button">Login with Facebook</div>

    </body>
 </html>
```

FYI: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/
check authentication section

Comment: Ah, I think that's it. No I need to try to understand how the authentication works.. I dont get it how I, for example, get the users email address?

Comment: _“I dont get it how I, for example, get the users email address?”_ – by querying the Graph API, of course. `FB.api("/me", function(response) { … });` (And don’t forget to get necessary permission first.)