# Make facebook login not start until button clicked

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

Right now my facebook login code automatically logs someone in when they visit the page. Which is not good.

How can I make it so it only logs them in if they click the on the login button? I tried a couple of things but they didn't seem to work

```
<script>
  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
      $.post("includes/login.php", {
            token: accessToken
        })
  .success(function() {
            location.reload();
        });
    }
  }
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'xxx',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.5' // use version 2.2
  });

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>

<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email,user_friends,user_birthday,user_location" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>
```

Comment: That is what is _supposed_ to happen. Trying to get it to behave differently might be a more complex issue. You could try and not call `FB.getLoginStatus`, and initialize the SDK with the explicit parameter set to _not_ check the login status – but I don’t know if that will have any influence on the `<fb:login-button>`. You might need to replace it with your own button, that then calls `FB.login` when clicked to perform login.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript SDK automatically login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223226/javascript-sdk-automatically-login)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution:

Make sure you have status: true in your init otherwise it will be blocked as a popup. Hope fully this helps someone else.

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'xxx',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.5', // use version 2.2
    status: true
  });

};

// Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

$('#facebook').on('click', function() {
 $("#facebook").html('Logging In...');
   FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
         var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
         $.post("includes/login.php", {
            token: accessToken
         })
         .success(function() {
            location.reload();
         });
      } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        login();
      } else {
        login();
      }
   });
});

function login()
{
    FB.login(function(response) {
       if (response.authResponse) {
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
         $.post("includes/login.php", {
            token: accessToken
         })
         .success(function() {
            location.reload();
         });
        } else {
          $("#facebook").html('Sign In With Facebook');
        }
    }, {scope: 'public_profile,email,user_friends,user_birthday,user_location'});
}
</script>
```

Comment: `status: true` _will_ make the SDK check if the user is logged in to Facebook and has previously authorized your app – so from the SDK’s perspective, the user _will_ already be logged in to your app.

Comment: yeah, the reason I did that was because it was blocking the popup of the facebook permissions and that seemed to fix it. Is there a better way to stop the popup from getting blocked?

Comment: What’s blocking the popup is that you're not calling `FB.login` directly on the user interaction of clicking the `#facebook` element, but only in the callback of the asynchronous `FB.getLoginStatus` call … that makes it not connected directly to the initial click any more, and therefor the browser blocks it.

Comment: is there a better way to make it not block the pop up than what I'm doing?

Comment: You’d need to call `FB.login` directly in the click handler for your button, without wrapping it into `FB.getLoginStatus`. But that would of course mean that the login popup opens every time, since you do not want to check login status when the user enters your site already. (In case the user already authorized your app, the popup will just open and close itself again.)

Comment: so the only way to not have the popup blocked is to have that box popup everytime for a split second when they have already authorized the app?

Comment: … or to check login status when the user enters the site, which you’re opposed to for some reason …?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<script>
      // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
      function statusChangeCallback(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
          var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
          $.post("includes/login.php", {
                token: accessToken
            })
      .success(function() {
                location.reload();
            });
        }
      }
      function checkLoginState() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
      }

      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'xxx',
        cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                            // the session
        xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
        version    : 'v2.5' // use version 2.2
      });

      };

      // Load the SDK asynchronously
      (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    </script>

    <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email,user_friends,user_birthday,user_location" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
    </fb:login-button>

     - List item
```